# How to solve this non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this non-linear differential equation using substitution $\dfrac{y}{x}$ to $t$. However, I can't solve this equation.

$$
\text{xy$\prime $} = \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3+y
$$

How to solve this equation and what's the general solution?

Thanks.

Comment: If $y=xt$, $y^{\prime}=xt^{\prime}+t$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you change the dependent variable to $u=y/x$, as you said, the equation becomes $x^2u'=u^3$, which can be immediately be solved by separating variables.

Show us what you tried and we may help you with it.

Comment: Just a comment, I think that you get x^2 u' = u^3

Comment: @Adrián: indeed, that was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

The substitution $u = \frac{y}{x}$ works. What you have is

$y = ux$

i.e., $ y' = x u' + u$

or $x y' = x^2 u' + y$

Substituting this into your equation, we get

$x^2 u' = u^3$

Which can be solved using standard methods.

Comment: May I observe that this is exactly what I wrote?

Comment: Indeed Mariano. I should have given my answer as a comment, but my rep wasn't high enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Is this right?

\begin{align}
\text{xy$\prime $} = \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3+y \\ \\
\frac{y}{x}=u, \\
y = \text{ux}, \\
\text{y$\prime $} = \text{u$\prime $x} + u \\ \\
x^2\text{u$\prime $} = u^3 \\
\int \frac{1}{u^3} \, du =\int \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx \\
-\frac{1}{2u^2} = -\frac{1}{x} + c \\
u^{2 }= \frac{1}{\frac{2}{x}+c} \\
y^{2 }= \frac{x^2}{\frac{2}{x}+c} \\
y = x\left(\frac{2}{x}+c\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Ooops.. my LaTex code is not working.

Comment: What are you trying to do with those $ inside \text{}?

Comment: How can I insert new line in LaTex code?

Comment: Okay, it's working finally.

Comment: I think it's right. Thanks guys.